# How to host wcf rest and soap service in a single application

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf-data-services

I have created a wcf service with both SOAP and REST feature enabled. When i start the service using visual studio the service gets started and i am able to consume it using webclient and browser using url.
But i want the service to be started with an application file (either a console or windows). And i must be able to use both the soap and rest feature.
Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="soap" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="restEndpointBehavior">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="restEndpointBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>

I tried adding the service reference to the console application that generated a app.config with the following code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1234/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/soap"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

i tried the method to host :
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceReference1. but i could not find the file Service1.(where Service1 is the class file that implements the IService1 contracts)
The Service1 is visible if a create a new project with only SOAP type.

What should i do to host both the SOAP and REST by a single application..

Answer (score 1):

Finally I came up with the solution. Its really easy.

1. Add a console project (or windows form application) for hosting
2. Start the service
3. Right click References in Solution explorer and select Add Service Reference
4. Give the service path or simply click discover
5. back in the host, create and object of service client using service host i.e

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/LoggerLibrary/Service1/");
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.LoggingLibrary), baseAddress);
host.Open();
```

6. and things goes finish here :)

Also instead of using Uri in the host we can define it in the config file. At this time the code will be simply:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.LoggingLibrary));
host.Open();
```